# html img cannot be appendChild()

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple javascript code which want to generate img randomly. My code is :

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    img{
        position: absolute;
    }
    div{
        position: absolute;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }
    #rightSide { left: 500px; 
                border-left: 1px solid black;
    }

</style>
<script>
    var numberOfFaces = 5;
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
    function generateFaces(){
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++){
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = "smile.png";

            var randomTop = Math.random() * 400;
            var randomLeft = Math.random() * 400;
            img.style.top = randomTop + "px";
            img.style.left = randomLeft + "px";
            document.getElementById("leftSide").appendChild(img);
        }

    }
    window.onload = generateFaces();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Matching Game</h1>
<p>click on the extra smiling face on the left</p>
<div id = "leftSide">
</div>
<div id = "rightSide">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Error message is "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at generateFaces", but my image "smile.png" is in the same directory as html, so the path is correct, what is the problem?  Thanks!

Comment: `window.onload = generateFaces();` should be `window.onload = generateFaces;`

Answer (score 0):

Change `window.onload = generateFaces();` To

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", generateFaces);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    img {
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    div {
      position: absolute;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    
    #rightSide {
      left: 500px;
      border-left: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var numberOfFaces = 5;
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");

    function generateFaces() {
      for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "smile.png";

        var randomTop = Math.random() * 400;
        var randomLeft = Math.random() * 400;
        img.style.top = randomTop + "px";
        img.style.left = randomLeft + "px";
        document.getElementById("leftSide").appendChild(img);
      }

    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", generateFaces);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Matching Game</h1>
  <p>click on the extra smiling face on the left</p>
  <div id="leftSide">
  </div>
  <div id="rightSide">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, and now I want to generate five images in left side and use cloneNode to copy it to the right side, my code is: var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide"); leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true); leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild); document.getElementById("rightSide").appendChild("leftSide‌​Images"); Error message is that Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.at generateFaces. What is the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to set a handler by invoking the `generateFaces` function instead of referencing it; `generateFaces()` should be `generateFaces`.

Due to that error, `document.getElementById("leftSide")` is invoked prematurely and returns `null` because the element doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Thanks, and now I want to generate five images in left side and use cloneNode to copy it to the right side, my code is: 
      
       
      var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
      leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
      leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
      document.getElementById("rightSide").appendChild("leftSideImages");

Error message is that Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.at generateFaces. What is the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I found your code is working fine, i just wrote the `script` tag before the  `</body>` tag and it works. here is the working code

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    img {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    }
    
    div {
      position: absolute;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    
    #rightSide {
      left: 500px;
      border-left: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Matching Game</h1>
  <p>click on the extra smiling face on the left</p>
  <div id="leftSide">
  </div>
  <div id="rightSide">
  </div>



  <script>
    var numberOfFaces = 5;
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");

    function generateFaces() {
      for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/39cluesidea/images/2/26/Smile.png/revision/latest?cb=20110217131619";

        var randomTop = Math.random() * 400;
        var randomLeft = Math.random() * 400;
        img.style.top = randomTop + "px";
        img.style.left = randomLeft + "px";
        theLeftSide.appendChild(img);
      }

    }
    window.onload = generateFaces();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, and now I want to generate five images in left side and use cloneNode to copy it to the right side, my code is: var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide"); leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true); leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild); document.getElementById("rightSide").appendChild("leftSide‌​Images"); Error message is that Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.at generateFaces. What is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: use
  

    `var leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);`


 and omit the double quote and write as the following

  `document.getElementById("rightSide").appendChild(leftSideImages);`

hope this may help and don't forget to upvote.